EntityFramework - Implement Scaffolding in a Console Application
I have a console application (created with .NET 8).
This application should perform the scaffolding (reverse engineering) of a SQL server database.
I cannot use scaffolding via the command line for some reasons. Therefore I want to use the
mentioned console application.
In my console application project I referenced the following Nuget packages:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design Version=8.0.4
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Version=8.0.4
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools Version=8.0.4

Unfortunately, I can't find any code examples of how to program the scaffolding in C#.
(parameterization and executing the scaffolding).
I would be very happy if one of you could show me how I can do this.
With kind regards
Christian
I tried a lot of research on the internet but found no examples.

Hi Kanavos,
the reason not only scaffolding by command line is that the tool internally tracks changes in the database schema und writes it's own fluent code. This means the tool investigates a lot of databases find's out the changes and generates the fluent part.

What reasons? Scaffolding is a development operation that happens infrequently. If you can't run the tools you probably can't use the scaffolding code either. In any case EF is open source. All the package code is available in Github. The code you look for is the DbContextScaffoldCommand which in turn calls

the tool internally tracks changes in the database schema und writes it's own fluent code that sounds like a very different question - how to use your own custom scaffolding. The EF scaffolding code will generate the same model classes and metadata as the tool. In fact, if you check the Github link, you'll see that the tool command is more or less a wrapper for the scaffold operation.

It's possible to customize the generated EF code using T4 templates. You can also use EF Core Power Tools as a VS plugin or through the CLI and customize the code using Handlebars templates, not just T4

Do you want to use scaffold to generate entities and dbcontext files? But where the files you want to place and how will you use them?
